# State not updating when printing on same function where updating in React Js

Tags: reactjs

On click of a button, I am updating state and it's successfully updating and changing the value of my input box and printing on screen, But when I am console.log state variable in that function where i am updating it (You can see the console.log in the changeState function). It didn't changed. Below is my code for that.

```
 import React from 'react';

 class Refs extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {
      data: ''
     }
     this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
     this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
   };
   updateState(e) {
     this.setState({data: e.target.value});
   }
   changeState() {
     this.setState({data: 'Hi coding!'});
     console.log(this.state.data);
   }
   render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <input value = {this.state.data} onChange = {this.updateState}></input>
        <h4>{this.state.data}</h4>
        <button onClick = {this.changeState}>CLEAR</button>
     </div>
    );
   }
 }
export default Refs;
```

Answer (score 1):

this.setState() is actually asynchronous.

The state was not updated when you console.log the value.

If you want to run some code when the state is updated, you can pass a callback to the setState() as mentioned in the comment by @Nikko.

```
this.setState( {data: 'Hi coding!'}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.data)} 
);
```

You should read this:

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value

Comment: Also to add: `this.setState( {data: 'Hi coding!'}, () => {console.log(this.state.data)} );` will print the updated value of the state

Comment: Yes, definitely. We can pass a callback to setState. Updating my answer. Thanks

Comment: I am using setTimeout, and it is giving me error now: "Can not read property data of undefined". And also please tell me what is "asynchronous".

Comment: setTimeout is not a good option, please use the code suggested by @NikkoKhresna.

Comment: Yes, I tried your answer @NikkoKhresna & it works fine. But please explain me what is asynchronous or give me any refrence. Thanks.

Comment: I've included a link in the answer.

Comment: But it didn't help me to find out, what the asynchronous is?

Comment: Read this https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527 and if it does not help, Google. :)

Comment: Asynchronous means: processes do not wait for previous processes to finish. So your `console.log` do not wait for `setState` completed modifying the value of `state`. For nore details, google: async vs sync. If you cant grasp the concept we'll be here to help u again. Nice day

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing function as a `props` so

call just function as you have in the same function

```
     <div>
        <input value = {this.state.data} onChange = {() => this.updateState()}></input>
        <h4>{this.state.data}</h4>
        <button onClick = {(e) => {e.preventDefault(); this.changeState();}>CLEAR</button>
     </div>
```